# Review this ER Diagram?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship, erd

> You have been asked to design a database for the university
>   administartion, which records the following information:
>
> - All students necessarily have a unique student ID, a name, and, a university email address.
> - Each student is also either an undergraduate or a graduate student.
> - Each graduate student has an adviser.
> - Each undergraduate student has a major.
> - Students take courses. A student may take one, multiple, or, no courses.
> - Each course has a course number, name, and, days of the week the course is scheduled.

[image]

- Is my ER Diagram correct?
- Should `WeekDay` be an entity? Why or Why not? Do you think that it should be a multi-valued attribute? Why?
- Should `Undergraduate Student` and `Graduate Student` be separate entities? Why or Why not?

Please, ignore the absence of cardinalities for the moment.

Comment: You're missing cardinalities, I'd add those. I see no particular reason WeekDay should be an entity either.

Comment: @Fang, explain as an answer, plz.

Comment: You want to ignore cardinalities, yet is is the M:Nness of Scheduled that gives each course multiple weekdays and a weekday multiple courses. PS Please give a reference for your E-R diagramming conventions & "multi-valued attribute" terminology.

Comment: I agree with @Fang. Whenever you are developing an ER-Diagram you must put the cardinalities. Do not forget them. They are very important, even to work in established relationships.

Answer (score 0):

Making Weekday an entity would imply that you would make your own table for weekday. That, in general, is only useful if weekday should hold further attributes. In terms of the simple scenario you provided, making weekday an entity is redundant, and would only bloat your design. Of course, this MIGHT change depending on whether you want to extend your design in the future.